# ExtJS - Overriding the FieldSet xType and adding a function does not seem to work?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am developing a web application and I want to check if my fieldSet is dirty. The first thing I attempted was `fieldSet.isDirty();` but I soon met with an error as the function `isDirty()` cannot be applied to the fieldSet xType. Wanting to still use an elegant solution, I then wrote an override for the fieldSet. My override looks like:

```
Ext.define('myApp.override.form.FieldSet', {
override: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',

sampleOverride: function(){
    console.log("hi! sample override function entered");
},

checkForDirtyFields: function(){
    me = this;
    return this.getFields().findBy(function(f){
        return f.isDirty();
    });
} 
});
```

As you can see, I wrote 2 functions, one as an example, and the other, for checking dirty fields inside the fieldSet. Upon trying to use it in my controller as:

```
fieldSet.checkForDirtyFields();
fieldSet.sampleOverride();
```

I am greeted by an error: `Uncaught TypeError: fieldSet.sampleOverride is not a function`

Am now legitimately confused. I've written overrides for the Panel XType and I am able to use them as intended (for clearing dirty status, for clearing the fields inside a form, etc). However, it seems that I can't make an override function for the fieldset.

Comment: There's no reason that shouldn't work. Put together a test case.

Comment: I found a work around. I'll be posting my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disappointing. I found a work around. My issue was that I had more than 1 store whose data is shown in a form, separated by fieldSets. The issue lies in saving the data in the page and using `isDirty()` to check if any changes needs to be committed. Checking for `form.isDirty()` would return true even if the fieldSet for one store was changed.

What I did was that after doing `form.updateRecord(record);`, I checked with `record.isModified();` to see if there is a change that needs to be committed. If it returns true, I proceed with my store syncing. If it returns false, then the record wasn't modified and I go on with my code.

Now, if you'd really want a function call, I suggest making a controller that takes a fieldSet/fieldContainer, go through the elements, and check the elements if any of those return false when checked with dirty.